# Access SQL Match To Unique Value

Tags: sql, ms-access, match, relationship

I have two different sets of data from two different sources that I am trying to combine to create a 'Pick List' stored in the 'SD' table. A simple extract of the data is as per below.

The common relationship between the two are `SKU`. `SKU` in the `SD` table gives us the quantity we require for the pick and can be more than one. `SKU` in table `Stock'`can have more than one of the same `SKU` but each has their own unique label ID.

SD Table:

```
SKU     Shoot Date
4PYCD   14/06/2015
4PYCE   14/06/2015
4PYCF   14/06/2015
4PYCF   14/06/2015
```

Stock Table:

```
SKU ID
4PYCD   Z1234
4PYCD   Z2345
4PYCE   H8767
4PYCF   H7890
4PYCF   Z3456
4PYCF   I8976
4PYCF   P0989
4PYCF   Z1236
```

For the example we have 2 `SKU`'s required on the shoot, and 5 available 'In Stock'. I need a query to feed the first 2 matched Label ID's from the `Stock` table as a match against the `SKU`'s requested in the `Pick List` table.

Desired Result:

```
SKU     Shoot Date  ID
4PYCD   14/06/2015  Z1234
4PYCE   14/06/2015  H8767
4PYCF   14/06/2015  H7890
4PYCF   14/06/2015  Z3456
```

I have tried to play around with the `TOP` function for a good while now with various subqueries but I can get anything to give me quite what I need, can anyone help ?

Current simple SQL setup (Without my attempts of using `TOP`):

```
SELECT tblSD_F4.SKU, tblStock.[Label No]
FROM tblStock RIGHT JOIN tblSD_F4 ON tblStock.SKU = tblSD_F4.SKU;
```

Kind Regards

Comment: You mention two tables, however your query has three tables, I assume because `SD` is short for `ScheduleDate`?.  I also feel like you swap between names like "Pick List" and "Pick Request" table names.  Can you update with uniform naming that you use throughout the whole question?

Comment: Sure, made those ammends. Thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS-Access? It doesn't make sense to have both tags in a question, unless you're doing some kind of multiple-database application.

Comment: @Barmar I assume that he just put those tags in there because he might not be familiar with the difference yet.  The tags seemed like a bit of a shotgun approach ;-)  I just assumed based off of the syntax in his query with the [ ] in there.

Comment: @Newd I assume so, too. I'm trying to prompt him to figure out the difference and fix the question.

Comment: Apologies, the mySQL tag has been removed, I am working in MS-Access.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
SELECT TOP 2 tblSD_F4.SKU, tblStock.[Label No]
FROM tblStock 
INNER JOIN tblSD_F4 
ON tblStock.SKU = tblSD_F4.SKU;
```

Basically while that is a little rough hand, it should give you two random matching records from your `tblStock` table.  It seems like your main issue is that you are doing a `RIGHT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`.

I apologize if the syntax is off, Access really spoils me when it comes to Query Designing.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. Unfortunately that doesnt work as both Label ID's pulled through as the same. There is also the possibility that items on the SD table may not be in the Stock table, so this is why there is a right join.

Comment: What I effectively require, and i have tried to do so with `COUNT` but cant quite get to a resolution is `COUNT` per group on 'SKU' in the SD table. Then use that `COUNT` as a variable for `TOP` per 'SKU'. Hope that makes sense?!